# Error message: Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following json string. In scala I want to extract some fields and save them in a new json.

> {"query":"doi:10.1186/s13612-016-0045-3","result":[{"total":"1","start":"1","pageLength":"10"}],"records":[{"identifier":"doi:10.1186/s13612-016-0045-3","url":[{"format":"","platform":"","value":"http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s13612-016-0045-3"}],"title":"Technology
>   and Reflection: Mood and Memory Mechanisms for
>   Well-Being","creators":[{"creator":"Konrad,
>   Artie"},{"creator":"Tucker, Simon"},{"creator":"Crane,
>   John"},{"creator":"Whittaker, Steve"}],"publicationName":"Psychology
>   of
>   Well-Being","issn":"2211-1522","openaccess":"true","journalid":"13612","doi":"10.1186/s13612-016-0045-3","publisher":"Springer","publicationDate":"2016-06-15","volume":"6","number":"1","issuetype":"","topicalCollection":"","startingPage":"1","copyright":"©2016
>   The
>   Author(s)","genre":"OriginalPaper","abstract":"AbstractBackgroundWe
>   report a
>   ..."}],"facets":[{"name":"subject","values":[{"value":"Biological
>   Psychology","count":"1"},{"value":"Health
>   Psychology","count":"1"},{"value":"Neuropsychology","count":"1"},{"value":"Positive
>   Psychology","count":"1"},{"value":"Psychology","count":"1"},{"value":"Quality
>   of Life
>   Research","count":"1"}]},{"name":"pub","values":[{"value":"Psychology
>   of
>   Well-Being","count":"1"}]},{"name":"year","values":[{"value":"2016","count":"1"}]},{"name":"country","values":[{"value":"United
>   States","count":"1"},{"value":"USA","count":"1"}]},{"name":"type","values":[{"value":"Journal","count":"1"}]},{"name":"keyword","values":[{"value":"Emotion","count":"1"},{"value":"Memory","count":"1"},{"value":"Mood","count":"1"},{"value":"Reflection","count":"1"},{"value":"Reminiscence","count":"1"},{"value":"Technology
>   mediated
>   reflection","count":"1"},{"value":"Well-being","count":"1"}]}]}

In particular I want to get the following new json object (i.e. extract fields "creators","publicationName" and "abstract", and **rename them accordingly**):

> {"creators":[{"creator":"Konrad, Artie"},{"creator":"Tucker,
>   Simon"},{"creator":"Crane, John"},{"creator":"Whittaker,
>   Steve"}],"pubTitle":"Psychology of
>   Well-Being","pubAbstract":"AbstractBackgroundWe report ..."}

This is my current code, but I the error message says `Error:(137, 27) No Json serializer found for type play.api.libs.json.JsResult[org.test.Publication]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type. val json = Json.toJson(processedPubl)`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

case class Creator(creator: String)
case class Publication(pubTitle: String, creators: Seq[Creator], pubAbstract: String)

val jsonstring = ... // this is the raw string provided 
                     // at the beginning of this post

implicit val publReads: Reads[Publication] = (
        (JsPath \ "publicationName").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "creators").read[Seq[Creator]] and
        (JsPath \ "abstract").read[String]
    ) (Publication.apply _)

val processedPubl = Json.parse(jsonstring).validate[Publication](publReads)

val json = Json.toJson(processedPubl)
```

Comment: You could try json-play or sphere-json, both seem fine [link] (http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/)

Comment: @sarnthil: Thank you. I updated my post. I still have an error message when I run the core.

Comment: Why don't you implement a Writer? Error message is obvious.

Comment: @PavelS. Could you  please give an example? I am not so experienced working with play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Creator(creator: String)
case class Publication(pubTitle: String, creators: Seq[Creator], pubAbstract: String)

val jsonString = ...

implicit val creatorFormat = Json.format[Creator]
implicit val publWrites = Json.writes[Publication]
implicit val publReads: Reads[Publication] = (
  (JsPath \ "publicationName").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "creators").read[Seq[Creator]] and
  (JsPath \ "abstract").read[String]
)(Publication.apply _)

val input = Json.parse(jsonString).as[Publication]
val output = Json.toJson(input)
```

`Reads` is something that is used during reading from JSON (`input` uses this) and `Writes` is something that is used during writing to JSON (`output` uses it). Together they form something called `Format`. Since you're using case classes in your code, you can autogenerate those Reads/Writes/Formats using play-json methods.

Comment: I think it does not take into account that the field `publicationName` should be written as `pubTitle`, and `abstract` as `pubAbstract`. In other words, I should rename original titles of fields, and save their values with new titles in the final JSON. That's why I used Read.

Comment: Which version of Scala do you use? I am getting this error in 2.11.4: `Error:(122, 46) can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala implicit val creatorFormat = Json.format[Creator]`

Comment: Sorry, my scala version is 2.11.8, not 2.11.4

Comment: I am using Scala 2.11.8 as well. Are you using Maven or SBT? Can you show me how do you declare Play dependency in your build file?

Comment: I am using Maven: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-json_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: As you can see, you're using play-json compiled against Scala 2.10. You should use `play-json_2.11`

Comment: Ah, I haven't noticed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question. I executed the code, but it seems to get stuck. It does not output any result. Does it work fine for you with my initial JSON? I guess that's because my fields (creators, publicationName, abstract) are nested and the program cannot find them...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116885/discussion-between-pawel-jurczenko-and-klue).